# gnu find weirdness: filename wildcards broken?

Tags: linux, bash, find

`find` is behaving as if I am NOT quoting wildcards in -name patterns, but I AM quoting them:

```
/var/log # find . -name '*.gz'
find: paths must precede expression: dmesg.1.gz
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

/var/log # find . -name dmesg.1.gz
./dmesg.1.gz
/var/log # echo '*.gz'
*.gz
```

I know this used to work correctly - and it still does on other machines of mine. What could cause this behavior?

My bash version: GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)

My find version: find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2

/proc/version: Linux version 3.2.0-4-686-pae (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u3

Comment: Have you checked for aliases, functions or scripts called `find` that mishandle the arguments they're given?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Only to the extent that `which find` returns `/usr/bin/find` as expected.

Comment: That's useful...try `alias` to see aliases, and … is it `typeset -f` to see functions? (Yes, either `typeset -f` or — the native Bash way instead of Korn shell compatibility way — `declare -f`.)  Since `find` is behaving differently from `echo`, there must be something about `find` that is odd.  You could also try `command find . -name '*.gz'` which should run the command rather than an alias or function — or, indeed, `/usr/bin/find . -name '*.gz'`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: that did it - I had a `find()` function defined, and `command find` works as expected. Found it with `set | grep find`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>*Tranferring comments to answer.*</sup>

Have you checked for aliases, functions or scripts called `find` that mishandle the arguments they're given?

> Only to the extent that `which find` returns `/usr/bin/find` as expected.

That's useful … try `alias` to see aliases, and … is it `typeset -f` to see functions? (Yes, either `typeset -f` or — the native Bash way instead of Korn shell compatibility way — `declare -f`.) Since `find` is behaving differently from `echo`, there must be something about `find` that is odd. You could also try:

```
command find . -name '*.gz'
```

which should run the command rather than an alias or function — or, indeed:

```
/usr/bin/find . -name '*.gz'
```

> That did it - I had a `find()` function defined, and `command find` works as expected. Found it with `set | grep find`.

Glad that solved it!